# How can I excecute the tasks in the queue by using exactly 2 threads,considering a queue with tasks(task1,task2,task3,task1,task2,task3,...)

Tags: java, multithreading

case:
    **considered you have a queue with tasks(task1,task2,task3,task1,task2,task3,...),
    how can I excecute the tasks in the queue by using exactly 2 threads.**

requirement:

- 1.one thread should execute task1 and task2, anthoner should do task3, or conversely
     because some limited conditions eg. limited outside resources
- 2.task3 should always be executed after finishing to execute task1 and task2
     in the exactly order of the queue
- 3.should consider the diff situation ,eg the time consuming of task1,task2
     and task3 may be totally different
- 4.should` not come out dead loop

  [figure for flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMS6b.png)

**CODE**

```
    public class testRunManager {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BaseTask> tasks = new  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            tasks.add(new Task1());
            tasks.add(new Task2());
            tasks.add(new Task3());
        }
        BaseRunManager.getInstance().addTasks(tasks);
        Thread thread1 = BaseRunManager.getInstance().getNewThread(TaskThread.Type.BeforeWards);
        Thread thread2 = BaseRunManager.getInstance().getNewThread(TaskThread.Type.AfterWards);

        //start
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();


    }

    }

    public class TaskThread extends Thread{
    enum Type{
        BeforeWards,
        AfterWards
    }

    Type type;


    public TaskThread(Type type,Runnable runnable){
        super(runnable);
        this.type = type;

    }

    }

    public interface ShouldRunBeforeWardsJob {

    }

    public interface ShouldRunAfterWardsJob {

    }
    abstract public class RunController {
    public enum Performance {
        BUSYING,
        RUNNING,
        PAUSED,
    }

    protected enum ControlState {
        PAUSING,
        PAUSED,
        STOPING,
        RESUMING,
        RUNNING,
        STEPPING,
    }

    private ControlState state = ControlState.RUNNING;
    private Performance performance = Performance.BUSYING;
    private List<ControlListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    protected ReentrantLock controlLock  = new ReentrantLock();
    protected Condition controlCondition = controlLock.newCondition();

    public Performance getPerformance() {
        return performance;
    }

    protected ControlState getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void addListener(ControlListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(ControlListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (performance != Performance.RUNNING) {
            return;
        }
        setState(ControlState.PAUSING);
    }

    public void step() {
        if (performance != Performance.PAUSED) {
            return;
        }
        setState(ControlState.STEPPING);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (performance != Performance.RUNNING && performance != Performance.PAUSED) {
            return;
        }
        setState(ControlState.STOPING);
    }

    public void resume() {
        if (performance != Performance.PAUSED) {
            return;
        }
        setState(ControlState.RESUMING);
    }

    private void setPerformance(Performance p) {
        if (performance != p) {
            Performance old = this.performance;
            this.performance = p;
            for (ControlListener cl : listeners) {
                cl.performChanged(old, p);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void setState(ControlState state) {
        controlLock.lock();
        try {
            this.state = state;
            switch (this.state) {
                case RESUMING:
                case STEPPING:
                case PAUSING:
                case STOPING:
                    controlCondition.signal();
                    setPerformance(Performance.BUSYING);
                    break;
                case PAUSED:
                    setPerformance(Performance.PAUSED);
                    break;
                case RUNNING:
                    setPerformance(Performance.RUNNING);
            }
        }finally {
            controlLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public interface ControlListener {
        void performChanged(Performance oldState, Performance newState);
    }
    }   

    public abstract class BaseTask {
    enum State{
        FINISH,
        NOT
    }

    protected State state;

    public State getState(){
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    abstract void  runJob();

    abstract void doJob();

    }




    public class BaseRunManager {                
       private static BaseRunManager instance;
       private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BaseTask> tasks = new 
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

            public synchronized static BaseRunManager getInstance(){
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new BaseRunManager();
                }

                return instance;
            }

            public BaseRunManager(){

            }

            public void addTasks(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<BaseTask> tasks){
                this.tasks = tasks;
            }

            public Thread getNewThread(TaskThread.Type type){
                return new TaskThread(type,new BaseRunnable());
            }


            private  class  BaseRunnable extends RunController implements Runnable{
                private BaseTask curTask;
                private final AtomicBoolean afterwardsFinish = new AtomicBoolean(true);
                private final AtomicInteger beforewardsFinishNum = new AtomicInteger(0);
                private final AtomicInteger currentThreadNum = new AtomicInteger(0);
                 private final Condition condition = controlLock.newCondition();
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    currentThreadNum.incrementAndGet();
                    TaskThread curThread = (TaskThread)Thread.currentThread();


                    while (tasks.size()>0) {
                        //get task
                        controlLock.lock();
                        try {

                            curTask = tasks.peek();
                            if ((curTask instanceof ShouldRunBeforeWardsJob && curThread.type == TaskThread.Type.BeforeWards)
                                    || (curTask instanceof ShouldRunAfterWardsJob && curThread.type == TaskThread.Type.AfterWards)) {
                                tasks.poll();                      

                                if (curTask instanceof ShouldRunBeforeWardsJob) {
                                    curTask.runJob();
                                    beforewardsFinishNum.incrementAndGet();
                                    condition.signalAll();

                                } else if (curTask instanceof ShouldRunAfterWardsJob) {

                                    if (beforewardsFinishNum.get() / 2 != 0) {                               
                                        condition.await();
                                        curTask.runJob();
                                    }

                                }
                            } else {
                                condition.awaitNanos(20);
                                continue;
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            controlLock.unlock();
                        }

                    }            

                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BlockingQueue<BaseTask> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    final BlockingQueue<BaseTask> queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        tasks.add(new BaseTask("Task1"));
        tasks.add(new BaseTask("Task2"));
        tasks.add(new BaseTask("Task3"));
    }
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    BaseTask task = tasks.take();
                    task.run();
                    task = tasks.take();
                    task.run();
                    task = tasks.take();
                    queue2.offer(task);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    BaseTask task = queue2.take();
                    task.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread2.start();
    thread1.start();
}

private static class BaseTask implements Runnable {
    private final String name;

    public BaseTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(name + " ["
                + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. while if the task queue is actually corresponded to a tree panel , how to implement the stop/pause/resume functions for the queue?

Comment: I'd say up front: control the flow of tasks into the entry queue.

Comment: you mean :1. clear the queue of tasks when stopping 2. clone and clear the tasks when pausing 3. add the last tasks if not empty when resuming?

Comment: @zhuiri no, actually, I was thinking of controlling the process that adds the tasks in the queue, but I'm having second thoughts about that.

Comment: I have already shared all the related code in the github,  and the link is https://github.com/zhuiri/runtask, maybe it is easier to make some modifications

Answer (score 0):

In our latest project we have tried some thing like this.You can put dependent task in single worker thread so they will execute sequentially.

```
public interface SerializedRunnable extends Runnable {

    int getKey();

}

 public void execute(Runnable command) {
        final int key;
        if (command instanceof SerializedRunnable ) {
            key = ((SerializedRunnable ) command).getKey();
        }
 final int index =Math.abs(key) % size;
workers[index].execute(command);
```

Comment: maybe your solution is not exact one which I want, I upload figure to tell some details

Comment: what I am saying is task 1 Id suppose 0 It will go to Thread1 and Task 2 and task 3 id will be 1 and will submit to thread 2 so as queue will maintain so thread 2 will first execute task 2 and then Task 3.Let me know I f I have missing something